# Directional derivatives of $f(x,y) := \frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$ in $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Given is the function $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ with

$ f(x,y) :=  \frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2} \text{ for all } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \text{ and } 0 \text{ for all } (x,y) = (0,0)$

How can one prove that in all (bilateral) directional derivatives of $f$ exist in $(0,0)$?

I would have calculated the gradients

$$f_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2} = \dfrac{4yx}{x^4+y^2}-\dfrac{8yx^5}{\left(x^4+y^2\right)^2}$$

and

$$f_y = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{2x^2y}{x^4 + y^2} = \dfrac{2x^2}{y^2+x^4}-\dfrac{4x^2y^2}{\left(y^2+x^4\right)^2}$$

and then I would have calculated $f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$, but that would lead to division by zero.

I also thought that we need a vector for directional derivatives.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition of directional derivative at the origin, if we let $v = (a,b)$, we get that:
\begin{align*} 
D_{v}f(0,0) & = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f((0,0) + t(a,b)) - f(0,0)}{t}\\\\
& = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2t^{3}a^{2}b}{t^{3}(t^{2}a^{4} + b^{2})}\\\\
& = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2a^{2}b}{t^{2}a^{4} + b^{2}}\\\\
& = \frac{2a^{2}b}{b^{2}}\\\\
& = \frac{2a^{2}}{b}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: What exactly is $t(a,b)$?

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 The vector $v = (a,b)$ is the generic vector corresponding to the direction we are differentiating.

Comment: So $f(0,0$ is $0$, and $f(a,b)$ would be $\frac{2a^2b}{a^4+b^2}$

Where exactly does the $t^3$ come from?

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 In fact, one has

$$f((0,0) + t(a,b)) = f(ta,tb) = \dfrac{2(ta)^{2}(tb)}{(ta)^{4} + (tb)^{2}} = \dfrac{t^{3}a^{2}b}{t^{2}(t^{2}a^{4} + b^{2})}$$

Since there is an additional $t$ in the denominator, the proposed relation holds.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a $0/0$ indetermination for derivates means that they don't exist.
I drew this graph on geogebra. Here is the result:
[image: geogebra 1]
[image: geogebra 2]
You can see that your function is quite weirdy around $(0,0)$... So I'd say the function can't be derivated in $(0,0)$.